# How to read a document from Firestore in a Kotlin suspend fun

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple login/signup/dashboard app which i am working on. What i do is, i signup a user using firebase signup, and in that call, i add that user information in my collection and that gets added successfully and shows in collection as well. When i log in, the new user gets verified and in order to show the name of user on dashborad, i want to retrieve the name from collection using the ID of currently authenticated user. Look at the code below:

```
suspend fun getUserData() : User?{

    firestoreDB.collection("users").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            userInfo = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)!!
        }
    return userInfo
}
```

When I debugged this piece of code, i found that the part inside the .addOnSuccessListener is not getting execute at all. So, i get null in return.Can anyone one point out what am I doing wrong here?

The function is called from my viewmodel as:

```
fun getUserData() = viewModelScope.launch{
    val user= repository.getUserData()
    val username = user?.name
}
```

My Database looks like this:
[image: FireStoreDatabase]

Comment: Are you sure the success listener is never executed? If you put a breakpoint on `userInfo = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)` and run in the debugger again, does it reach that line?

Comment: Thats what i did to check it out. It doesn't reach that line

Comment: Did you check the log output? You might want to add a failure listener too, so you can check for errors.

Comment: I did not add the failure listener, i'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a `suspend fun` using the result of an asynchronous operation that returns a Play services Task object, don't use `addOnSuccessListener`.  get() is asynchronous and returns immediately with the Task object.  You will need a way to convert that Task into something that can work with coroutines to suspect the execution of the function until the Task is complete.

There is a library for this: [kotlinx-couroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services).  It will add an extension function `await()` to the task so you can use it in a suspend fun, an also use try/catch to trap errors.  In fact, that page shows you the code pattern you will use:

```
val snapshot = try {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("users/$id").get().await()
} catch (e: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
    return@async
}
```

In your case, more like this:

```
return firestoreDB
    .collection("users")
    .document(auth.currentUser!!.uid)
    .get()
    .await()
    .toObject(User::class.java)!!
```

Be sure to have the caller try/catch for errors.